# "And to you" or "you too"?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, american-english, british-english, politeness

I really like to chat with English folks, so I have wished them Merry Christmas. To my surprise I have noticed the following pattern — the British answered "and to you", but Americans "you too". The former was a form I hadn't seen before and I felt really awkward. My question is, which one is more polite and what is the difference between them?

Comment: I'd say they're both somewhat informal, but perfectly polite (some people seem to use *polite* for *formal*, but you can be very formal and extremely impolite, and vice versa).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are both elliptical forms of the sentence *"And Merry Christmas to you too"*. Either one is appropriate to use in informal situations. If you want to speak more formally, use the full sentence.

Answer (score 2):

"You too" sounds a little slovenly and maybe a touch insincere.
"And to you" sounds slightly more sincere and thus more polite.

To my British ears anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is something that depends on the region you are from. Both seem correct. Some say wish you the same and few say same to you.so its similar to these to phrases to use "**you too**" and **"And to you"**. since **"And to you"** also means the same, so you cannot say its incorrect.

Answer (score -4):

When English people use any new phrase, we are normally accepting it, because it is their mother tongue.

The others giving much care to its literal meaning.

So "and to you", "you too", "same to you" are all okay.